# ssh can't connect to CentOS at login screen

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I've a server that running CentOS 6.4 final, I tried putty to connect at login screen, it show Network error: Connection refused, but it works while I've logged in to server. Anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: add the output of your `ssh` command with `-vvv` option. having your config file `sshd.conf` could also help without that you will have no useful answer

Comment: Thanks your comment. It help and I figure out the major problem.

Comment: Is your home folder encrypted?